# Корректна ли функция? Алгоритм Евклида

Tags: алгоритм, javascript

Здравствуйте всем. Изобретаю велосипед. Алгоритм Евклида.

```
function evclide ( n, m ) {

var tmp = n % m;

    if ( tmp !== 0) {
        tmp = m % tmp ;
    };

    console.log (tmp);
};
```

Работает вроде правильно, но, может, есть какой-то подводный камень? (При условии n > m, проверку не делал, суть не в этом). И это же не рекурсия?

Answer (score 2):

[Алгоритм Евклида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%95%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0) для натуральных чисел a, b можно кратко выразить как:

```
НОД(a, 0) = a
НОД(a, b) = НОД(b, a % b)
```

Что можно реализовать на javascript как рекурсивно:

```
var gcd = function gcd(a, b) {
    return b ? gcd(b, a % b) : a;
}
```

Так и с помощью цикла:

```
var gcd_iter = function gcd_iter(a, b) {
    while (b) {
        var t = b, // [a, b] = [b, a % b]
            b = a % b, 
            a = t;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не сработает для чисел `n = 36`, `m = 10`.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо. Буду дальше думать.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм Евклида представляет собой цепочку однотипных операций вычисления остатка от деления и смены мест аргументов. Это реализуется либо рекурсивно, либо с помощью цикла. В вашем случае у вас всего одна операция, так что на примерах, где нужно провести несколько таких ответа верного ваша функция не даст.